# Mono.Cecil fails to process a Silverlight 5 assembly

Tags: .net, mono.cecil

When I am trying to read a Silverlight 5 assembly via [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) version 0.9.3.0, I am getting the following exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Version not supported: 5.0.5.0
------   
at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.GetCorlib(AssemblyNameReference reference) in C:\programming\mono.cecil\jbevain-cecil-5df660e\Mono.Cecil\BaseAssemblyResolver.cs:line 200
------  
at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name) in C:\programming\mono.cecil\jbevain-cecil-5df660e\Mono.Cecil\BaseAssemblyResolver.cs:line 117
....
```

It happens because the reference in the Silverlight project is to mscorlib 5.0.5.0 while the GetCorlib function doesn't seem to be handling these cases.

Is there a solution to this issue?

Comment: Report a bug at https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/issues @jbevain usually address issues fast :)

Comment: I am not sure it is an issue, as such, since there are various `#if !SILVERLIGHT` in the code. So it seems to be something that is already taken into some account and handled, I just don't understand how I can use a single mono.Cecil.dll to handle both regular .NET assemblies and Silverlight assemblies.

Comment: @leppie, google alerts work too :) I have a mail in only minutes after a question is asked on SO.

Comment: @JbEvain: Cool, never knew about that, time to investigate :)

Comment: @JBEvain: That IS fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cecil's default resolver doesn't handle Silverlight assemblies. It's easy to fix. Just pass your own resolver to your assemblies, and make sure it can resolve Silverlight assemblies:

```
var resolver = new DefaultAssemblyResolver ();
resolver.AddSearchDirectory ("path/to/silverlight/assemblies");

var assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly (
    assemblyFile,
    new ReaderParameters { AssemblyResolver = resolver });
```

Also, I strongly suggest you update from 0.9.3 to a newer release.